# Генерация составного идентификатора на стороне сервера

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Подскажите как правильно реализовать следующую логику получения уникального *ключа*. В ключ должны входить следующие данные: *год* и *месяц* создания строки в бд, а так же *порядковый номер* который каждый месяц начинается с 1, а в течении месяца  значение должно увеличиваться на единицу для каждой новой строки в бд.

Первая строка которая будет добавлена в таблицу должна иметь следующий уникальный идентификатор: `{Текущий год}{separator}{Текущий месяц}{separator}{Порядковый номер}`

На текущий момент это реализовано так:

1. Получаем последнюю строку из бд
2. *Парсим* уникальный идентификатор и складываем его в переменные: `year`, `month`, `number`
3. Получаем порядковый номер для акта: `currentNumber = currentMonth == month ? number++ : 1;`

   CREATE TABLE dbo.[table] (
     Id int IDENTITY,
     Number varchar(50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_table_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
   )

Прошу прощения если не смог донести основной смысл вопроса, мне не понятно как правильно реализовать именно получение порядкового номера документа, как гарантировать его уникальность в периоде одного месяца, и *обнулении* при смене месяца

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю создать отдельную таблицу, где будет фиксироваться последний ID в каждом месяце. Например что нибудь такого вида:

```
create table testSeq(
  date_str char(7) not null primary key,
  seq int not null
);
```

Получение очередного ID можно выполнить атомарно таким запросом:

```
merge testSeq as S
using (select '2018.08' as date_str, 1 as seq) N
   on N.date_str=S.date_str
when not matched then
  insert(date_str, seq) values(N.date_str, N.seq)
when matched then
  update set S.seq=S.seq+1
output INSERTED.seq;
```

Answer (score 2):

Как это сделано у нас.
1. При добавлении записи номер документа (речь ведь про номер документа, да?) не присваивается. Записи присваивается суррогатный ключ (Identity-столбец). Этот ключ триггером помещается в очередь обработки (в нашем случае Service Broker).
2. Обработчик очереди получает из очереди ключ, формирует для записи с этим ключом номер, присваивает этот номер записи.

Поскольку обработчик единственный, работает по принципу FIFO - мы можем гарантировать отсутствие блокировок и поддержание порядка. Поскольку обработчик асинхронный (создание записи не ожидает присвоения номера) - процесс создания записи это не замедляет.

Comment: *составной идентификатор - это действительно номер документа. Основной вопрос состоит как выполнить условия формирования ключа

Comment: [присоединяйтесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80851/discussion-between-bald-and-mirdin)

Answer (score 1):

Правильным будет использовать не естественный, а суррогатный ключ. И уже после добавления в базу данных строки формировать ваш "уникальный" ключ, если он вам для чего то нужен. В вашем же случае, поддерживать "уникальность", будет еще тем "геморроем".

**UPD** Про "уникальный идентификатор", нужный для печатных форм. лично я, не хранил бы, строку, которую необходимо парсить, а завел бы два поля - в одном хранил дату документа, в другом интовый порядковый номер, а "уникальный идентификатор" формировал в момент запроса.

**UPD 2 из чата** Получение номера уникального в течении месяца:

1. Получаем последнюю запись за прошлый месяц
2. Вычитаем ее `Id` из `Id` текущей записи
3. ...
4. PROFIT

Comment: я именно и хочу формировать ключ на стороне сервера(т.е. средствами бд), данный ключ мне нужен, он попадает в отчетные формы, вопрос то и состоит в том как *сгенерировать* ключ по описанным мной правилам

Comment: @Bald, есть некоторая разница между КЛЮЧОМ, то есть сущностью, однозначно идентифицирующую некую запись, и объектом который попадает в отчетные формы, и который не всегда даже надо хранить, а можно формировать непосредственно перед передачей в отчетную форму, например, в запросе.

Comment: @Bald  Касаемо же вашего формирования ключа: если учитывать, все сопутствующие факторы, например невозможность гарантировать получение именно ПОСЛЕДНЕЙ строки в таблице (наличие транзакций, триггеров, да и просто многопользовательского доступа будет этому мешать), необходимость поддерживать уникальность и неизменность идентификатора в "ручном режиме", и т.д., то ваш подход не хуже и не лучше любого другого костыля.

Comment: у меня есть `identity` в исходной таблице, и для связей между таблицами я именно его и использую, а *уникальный идентификатор* нужен для печатных форм, прошу прощения если не правильно выразился

Comment: добавил в вопрос таблицу, составной идентификатор это ни что иное как `Number`, уникальность можно контролировать созданием индекса по этому полю, оно вспомогательное и не является ключом в прямом смысле этого слова

Comment: @Bald, поправил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80851/discussion-between-bald-and-mirdin).